# Minecraft Server Resource Park Won't Change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-resource-packs

I am making an SCP Resource pack only for sounds. To do it, I added more sounds over time. I uploaded a version of the pack with two sound effects to dropbox, and set the dl=1, and the server was able to use those two sounds. However, I later added three more on my own computer, and updated the sounds.json. I tested the sounds by using them in-game myself, so I know they work. However, when I updated the old files on dropbox, by deleting the old and replacing them with the new, the server only loads 2 sounds, the two alarm sounds. When I download the resource park myself off of dropbox, it still works, so what gives? Can I not change the resource park of the server? A quick response would be appreciated, thank you!
The new link to the pack is https://www.dropbox.com/sh/frgwldwew0ghid1/AAAwJiAU5Tyki_sHcA4hbyqAa?dl=1, by the way.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes. I restarted the server several times. I also created other tries where I deleted the resource pack link and re-added to server.properties, but it still loads only the two songs that were there before.

Comment: Even if you delete them from all places it could possibly access them from? That's very weird.